# jwplayer preview image with controls bar

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm using jwplayer6.
I'm looking for a way to add the controls bar together with the preview image, right now it only shows the image with play icon on it but i also want the controls.

This is what i'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

Basically, i'm want to give the user the option to open the movie on full screen mode with one button click when the preview image display. since there is no api to trigger the fullscreen mode i thought about showing the preview page with the controls bar. Now i got an answer that i can't make that. 
any idea about a different way?

Comment: Once again, a perfectly clear question, one that will require a programming solution, is marked as "off-topic" by people who simply don't know anything about it. Most annoying thing about this site....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with our player - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407439-adding-preview-thumbnails

Comment: Ethan, I think you've misunderstood the question. He's not talking about preview thumbnails. He's talking about the initial poster image, before you ever hit "Play." He wants to see the full controlbar at that stage.

Comment: Ah, got it, then yes, that is not possible.

Comment: I didn't think so, but thought there might be something lurking in the API. An unusual use case, in any event. The YouTube player, for example, behaves like JW Player - if you don't autostart it, you get just the big "Play" button, with no controlbar.

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your help. I updated my question if you could please take a look. Thanks again!

Comment: You still have this tagged as a JW Player question. It's been answered - you can't do this with JW Player. You'll have to change the tags on the question if you're looking for some other solution.

Comment: but i'm still looking for jwplayer solution.

Comment: This is not something that is supported, I'm afraid.

Comment: Which part of "you can't do that with JW Player" are you not getting?

Comment: @MisterNeutron - you know there's a better, nicer way to answer?

Comment: That's why I told you to change the tags on your question. That's the only way you're going to have any hope of getting a decent answer. I'm trying to help you, but you're fighting it all the way. There is no JW Player solution. The solution will have to come from somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly, this is not something that is supported in the JW Player.